# Error: no hay claves primarias o candidatas en la tabla de referencia

Tags: sql, sql-server

Cuando ejecuto la línea

```
ALTER TABLE factura ADD FOREIGN KEY (fk_numero_documento)REFERENCES usuario(numero_documento);
```

esta me genera errror

> No hay claves primarias o candidatas en la tabla de referencia 'usuario' que coincidan con la lista de columnas de referencia en la clave externa

Éste es el código completo:

```
create table tipo_documento
(
    id_tdocumento VARCHAR(5) primary key,
    nombre_tipo_doc VARCHAR(30)  not null,
    siglas VARCHAR(5) unique not null 
);

create table usuario
(
    numero_documento varchar(25) not null,
    primer_nombre varchar(25) not null,
    segundo_nombre varchar(25),
    primer_apellido varchar(25) not null,
    segundo_apellido varchar(25),
    email VARCHAR (30) unique  not null,
    contraseña VARCHAR(15),
    fk_id_rol smallint ,
    fk_id_tdocumento VARCHAR(5),
    fk_id_plan int,
    primary key(numero_documento, fk_id_tdocumento)
);

create table factura
(
    id_factura int primary key ,
    total float  not null, 
    fecha datetime not null,
    fk_id_tpago int,
    fk_id_plan int,
    fk_numero_documento VARCHAR (25)
);

ALTER TABLE factura ADD FOREIGN KEY (fk_numero_documento)REFERENCES usuario(numero_documento);
```

Answer (score 0):

> El error va relacionado a que las llaves foráneas se vinculan con una única columna de una tabla principal que actúa como llave primaria, la cual debe ser del mismo tipo de dato.

Lo que yo haría es:

- Dejar como *llave primaria* solamente a: `numero_documento` asumiendo que ese registro en ningún momento se debe repetir, pues habla del registro numérico de un documento.
- Manejar un `CONSTRAINT` de tipo `UNIQUE` en `fk_id_tdocumento` para indicar que ese valor debe ser único por lo tanto no se debería estar repitiendo así evitamos duplicidades.

**Referencias**

- [`Foreign keys` documentación oficial](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-foreign-key-relationships?view=sql-server-2017)